# Terms not cancelling properly

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have defined

```
r1plus := (1/2)*(Sqrt[zetabar/zeta0] + Sqrt[zeta0/zetabar])
r1neg := (1/2)*(Sqrt[zetabar/zeta0] - Sqrt[zeta0/zetabar])
R1 := -r1neg/r1plus
T1 := 1/r1plus
```

and I want to calculate

```
FullSimplify[R1^2 + T1^2]
```

but the output I get is

```
(zeta0^2 + zetabar^2 + 
 2 zeta0 zetabar (1 - 
    2 Sqrt[zeta0/zetabar] Sqrt[zetabar/zeta0]))/(zeta0 - zetabar)^2
```

One can see that the sqrt's should cancel out, but I can't seem to get this to happen. I must be making a mistake in defining these things. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: State what do you know about the variables using `Assuming`.

Comment: If you write `Simplify[R1^2 + T1^2, {zeta0 > 0, zetabar > 0}]` you get 1. The same you get if they both are negative, but if one is positive and the other is negative you get a more complex result. Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you might use advanced Mathematica features for this case, but I think the simple methods are the best. I suggest the code

```
sqzz = Sqrt[zetabar/zeta0];
r1plus = (1/2)*(sqzz + 1/sqzz);
r1neg = (1/2)*(sqzz + 1/sqzz);
R1 = -r1neg/r1plus;
T1 = 1/r1plus;
(result = Factor[R1^2 + T1^2]) // InputForm
```

which produces the `result`

```
(zeta0^2 + 6*zeta0*zetabar + zetabar^2)/(zeta0 + zetabar)^2
```